# Remove xml node -Xelement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file from which only specific nodes have to be removed. The node name will be given as input from the user. How to remove the specific nodes which have requested from the user?

```
<Customers>    
  <Customer>    
    <id>michle</id>
    <address>newjersy</address>    
  </Customer>    
  <Customer>    
    <id>ann</id>
    <address>canada</address>    
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I have tried

```
var customer = new XElement("customer",
      from o in customers
      select 
          new XElement("id", id),
          new XElement("address", address)
        );
```

Customer will contain a new node

```
<Customer>    
  <id>ann</id>
  <address>canada</address>    
</Customer>
```

`doc.Element("customers").Elements(customer).ToList().Remove();`

but this is not working. How can I remove the element from the xml?

Comment: no. Im getting compile time error. Customer is a variable which is not allowed it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom,

Try this...

```
private static void RemoveNode(string sID)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\Projects\\RemoveNode.xml");

        var v = from n in doc.Descendants("Customer")
                     where n.Element("id").Value == sID
                     select n;
        v.Remove();
        doc.Save(@"D:\\Projects\\RemoveNode.xml");
    }
```

This removed one node when I called it using

```
RemoveNode("michle");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake is that you are creating new nodes that not attached with the source document instead of retrieving existed nodes from it.

You can use article ["Removing Elements, Attributes, and Nodes from an XML Tree"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693203.aspx) on MSDN as a guideline to manipulating XML data.

For example, use [`XNode.Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx) method to delete one node from the tree or [`Extensions.Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : XNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) to remove every node in the source collection of nodes:

```
doc.Descendants("Customer")
    .Where(x => x.Element("id").Value == id)
    .Remove();
```

But you also need to save document via [`Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save.aspx) method after that for commit your changes:

```
doc.Save();
```

Comment: getting the error Error 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveChild' and no extension method 'RemoveChild' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: when i tried customer.remove(), the error returned parent is missing

Comment: @TomCruise yeap because you are creating new nodes instead of reatrieving it from xml. See last link for details.

Comment: @TomCruise I updated my answer with the new details and references.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this way based on `id`

```
        xdoc.Descendants("Customer")
        .Where(x => (string)x.Element("id") == "michle")
        .Remove();
```