# How to remove tags from xml

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, ebay-api

i have a xml file i want to remove some tags from the file. My xml data is

```
    <GetCategoriesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2017-06-08T05:34:32.960Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>989</Version>
  <Build>E989_CORE_API_18131074_R1</Build>
  <CategoryArray>
    <Category>
      <BestOfferEnabled>true</BestOfferEnabled>
      <AutoPayEnabled>true</AutoPayEnabled>
      <CategoryID>20081</CategoryID>
      <CategoryLevel>1</CategoryLevel>
      <CategoryName>Antiques</CategoryName>
      <CategoryParentID>20081</CategoryParentID>
    </Category>
   </CategoryArray>
</GetCategoriesResponse>
```

I need to remove  from the file. so my result should be like this

```
      <Timestamp>2017-06-08T05:34:32.960Z</Timestamp>
      <Ack>Success</Ack>
      <Version>989</Version>
      <Build>E989_CORE_API_18131074_R1</Build>
      <CategoryArray>
        <Category>
          <BestOfferEnabled>true</BestOfferEnabled>
          <AutoPayEnabled>true</AutoPayEnabled>
          <CategoryID>20081</CategoryID>
          <CategoryLevel>1</CategoryLevel>
          <CategoryName>Antiques</CategoryName>
          <CategoryParentID>20081</CategoryParentID>
        </Category>
       </CategoryArray>
```

I have tried with this it is working. But its coming namespace in categoryarray

```
<CategoryArray xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Category>
      <BestOfferEnabled>true</BestOfferEnabled>
      <AutoPayEnabled>true</AutoPayEnabled>
      <CategoryID>20081</CategoryID>
      <CategoryLevel>1</CategoryLevel>
      <CategoryName>Antiques</CategoryName>
      <CategoryParentID>20081</CategoryParentID>
    </Category>
   </CategoryArray>

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
    XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
    nsm.AddNamespace("i", "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
    XmlNodeList node = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/i:GetCategoriesResponse/i:CategoryArray", nsm);

    XmlDocument xdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
    foreach (XmlNode xNodeI in node)
    {
        XmlNode newNode = xdoc1.ImportNode(xNodeI, true);
        xdoc1.AppendChild(newNode);
    }

    xmldoc = xdoc1;
    xmldoc.Save(path + @"\EbayCategories.xml");
```

Comment: Could you share your code so we can see what is wrong with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove xml node -Xelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196598/remove-xml-node-xelement)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis i need to remove opening and closing tags

Comment: Xml requires only one tag at root.  Removing GetCategoriesResponse will give an array of xml that will not work.